# ORACLE APEX Question on using Update / Save Button

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've created an APEX page based on a single table, which is then called by a another APEX page with a field value to be queried.
The page displays the record, which has a Primary Key consisting of 2 fields.
When I use the Update/Save button, it appears not to update the data, though it does not return any errors.
This works OK on other APEX pages where they are based on Tables with a single field Primary Key.

I would appreciate an explanation/solution from anyone who has had a similar problem and found a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no problem in principle with have a 2-column PK in Apex.  Maybe you have made a mistake in setting up the page?  I'm confused that you say the page is called with "a field to be queried" - don't you need to pass 2?

Comment: Sorry - I do pass the 2 key values to query on, not 1.

Comment: I have tried created an isolated APEX page to test this - Still no Update when no one column value is the unique identifier

Answer (score 1):

Your page should have a "Process Row of MYTABLE" process. Have a look in the details of the process, you'll find that it has the following attributes:

- Item Containing Primary Key Column Value
- Primary Key Column
- Item Containing Secondary Key Column Value
- Secondary Key Column

Your process should include both Primary and Secondary Keys.

Comment: I have made sure that both the Primary Key Column and the Secondary Key Column Values have been set in the Process Row of the Table.